# Add complete flag to E-mail

Tags: vba, outlook

I have this VBA code that I pulled and I attached it to a rule, so that it automatically prints the .pdf attachments and e-mail on arrival. Is it possible to add a flag if it successfully printed?

```
            Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias _
              "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, _
              ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, _
              ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

            Sub PrintAttachments(oMail As Outlook.MailItem)
              Dim colAtts As Outlook.Attachments
              Dim oAtt As Outlook.Attachment
              Dim sFile As String
              Dim sDirectory As String
              Dim sFileType As String

              sDirectory = "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\PDFS\Print\"

              Set colAtts = oMail.Attachments

              If colAtts.Count Then
                For Each oAtt In colAtts

                  sFileType = LCase$(Right$(oAtt.FileName, 4))

                  Select Case sFileType

            ' Add additional file types below followed by comma
                  Case ".pdf"

                    sFile = sDirectory & oAtt.FileName
                    oAtt.SaveAsFile sFile
                    oMail.PrintOut
                    ShellExecute 0, "print", sFile, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0
                  End Select
                Next

              End If

            End Sub
```

Comment: Which version of Outlook do you use?

Comment: I use outlook 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
            If oMail.Categories <> "Printed" Then
              Case ".pdf"

                sFile = sDirectory & oAtt.FileName
                oAtt.SaveAsFile sFile
                oMail.PrintOut
                oMail.Categories = "Printed"
                oMail.Save
                ShellExecute 0, "print", sFile, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0
                End Select
              Next
            Else
              MsgBox "It was already printed"
            End If
```

Comment: Thank you for attempting to assist me. Unfortunately this is not how I need it done. My original post simply requests the addition of a flag (or category) to be used after print. My original code is a run script rule that is executed on email arrival. This code is something that will continue to run overnight, so I cannot use code that simply works on selection and only prints the email. The code I provided prints the attachments and emails which is what I need. I am only requesting assistance in adding flags to my already existing code.

Comment: I ended having to move it around so that it worked, but I got it working. Thanks!